# Как установить булево значение вместо string(или char)?

Tags: c#

У меня есть строка:

```
public static bool status = %n%;
```

Мне нужно заменить за место `%n%` булево значение `true` или `false`

Пробую сделать так

```
string Text = Resources.Build;
Text.Replace("%n%" true);
```

Но студия возмущается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как преобразовать в `bool`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Признаюсь, я не совсем понимаю, что Вы делаете. Работаете с .resx файлами?

Но, так как Вы работаете с текстовыми данными, Вы не можете заменить подстроку непосредственно значением типа bool:

```
Text.Replace("%n%" true);
```

Используйте строковое представление:

```
string Text = Resources.Build;
Text.Replace("%n%", "true");
```